# Good open source django project for learning

Tags: django

Can anyone suggest a good open source django project to learn django development.

Comment: The fact that this question was closed as "not constructive" when it has 63 up-votes and 37 favorites... this is exactly why I've all but completely stopped using SO.

Comment: Also, take a look at this: [Small Open Source Django Projects to get started](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/23/small-open-source-django-projects-to-get-started.html)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A great resource is [www.djangopackages.com](http://www.djangopackages.com/), which lists a lot of the notable Django apps out there, including links to their respective repos, popularity ratings, etc..

Another way to find popular projects is directly on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=django

Finally:

1. Awesome Django @ https://github.com/wsvincent/awesome-django
2. Awesome Python @ https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python

Answer (score 12):

[django-basic-apps](http://code.google.com/p/django-basic-apps/) is also a very good start to learn django and reusable apps. These apps are simple enough and code is well written.

Comment: +1 on django-basic-apps. Nathan continues to update it and it's a great starter point for noobs to Django.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to learn the popular reusable app feature of Django I would suggest [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com), and you also may want to look at [Django-Mingus](http://github.com/montylounge/django-mingus). I'm the author behind Mingus and I recently posted a list of the apps included in Mingus along with a description of how and why they are used. It maybe helpful in finding some projects you may want to use yourself. Here's a link: "[The apps that power Django-Mingus](http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/sep/24/apps-that-power-django-mingus/)"

There's also a ton of Django projects on Google Code, GitHub, and BitBucket. Just search for "django".

Django-CMS, mentioned above, and Fein-CMS are both good CMS projects to dive into, and the screencasts by Eric are terrific - I absolutely suggest any noob to Django watch all 13 of those screencasts.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best for newbie: 13 screencasts "Django From the Ground Up" at **This Week In Django**<sup>#</sup>

edit: 
<sup>#</sup>the website is closed. [view archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080817043920/http://thisweekindjango.com/).

Answer (score 5):

I asked Malcolm Tredinnick a few weeks ago if there was a project he admired and he suggested Django Packages. [They keep their source on Github](https://github.com/opencomparison/opencomparison) .

I wouldn't say that it should be used as a Django tutorial but they have an admirable style of programming and I have picked up more than a few tips and tricks by reading their source. It is definitely a good example to learn from.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments on Django Packages. However, we moved the source code to https://github.com/opencomparison/opencomparison/:

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Waka Waka](http://github.com/bartTC/django-wakawaka). Its a very well written wiki, that should give you a good idea of how to develop in django. It is an application used by Pinax, which by itself should be huge, to learn.

You can also of course go through some of [ubernostrum's code](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/) like Registration, profiles and Contact Form, which are a standard in the django world. But as some of them involve dynamic forms, it may be best to get to it, after a little actual coding.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in running Django in App Engine, checkout out [this project](http://bitbucket.org/hudarsono/meblog). Here's a [demo.](http://hudarsono.me)