# Django - Where to save forms

Tags: django, forms, file, save

I like to keep my Django app organized and so I wonder where I should put the code of forms in? Should I write the code in the models file or should I create a new file (i.e. `forms.py`)?
Does Django have any guidelines for that I should use follow and where do most of the other developer put the forms in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are usually put inside the `forms.py` under a django app, just near the `models.py`. Though, if there are a lot of forms in the `forms.py`, you can make a package from it and split forms into logical parts.

Also see:

- [Django Applications best practices from LincolnLoop](http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/applications.html)
- [An Updated General Django Project (>= 1.5) Structure or Folder layout](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/updated-django-project-structure-or-folder-layout/)
- [Good open source django project for learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499543/good-open-source-django-project-for-learning)
- [Open-Source Django projects](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Open-SourceDjangoprojects)